# RSS feed items only link back to homepage of my blog, not the individual posts

Tags: rss

I've created an RSS feed, but when someone subscribes to it, either through Google or Yahoo! the only links showing up take them to the blog. And when someone clicks on the links it takes them to my blog whereas I want to show the blog content without people have to click on the link.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>cmg</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/blog</link>
  <description>cmg</description>
  <item>
    <title>cmg</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com/blog</link>
    <description>cmg</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

I've also put this link in the body of my site and not the head as I don't have access to the `<head>` using the CMS which doesn't allow me to enter any code apart from CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an RSS feed you have to make sure each `<item>` node points to a specific post. The channel elements will describe the site overall with the link back to the homepage and a short description. But it's the individual items that will show per post that need to be crafted.

In your case, your item(s) only shows the link to and content of the homepage, or copies what you have in the `<channel>` parent elements.

An example RSS feed with two posts would be like thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Example</title>
  <link>http://example.com/blog</link>
  <description>Description of entire site</description>
  <item>
    <title>Example blog post</title>
    <link>http://example.com/blog/example-blog-post</link>
    <description>One example straight from the individual</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Another post</title>
    <link>http://example.com/blog/another-post</link>
    <description>Another example of a single post</description>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

In the above example you'll note that each `<item>` has a uniquie `<link>` node which points to the permalink of that post as well as the description for it. These are separate and different to those of the `<channel>` overall.

When the user then subscribes to your feed, it will load the posts into their content aggregator and they will be able to read your posts without have to click back to the site.

You can have a link to the RSS anywhere on the page. If you add that as a `<link>` in the header, then it will allow browsers that can detect feeds to show the relevant icon, but it's not necessary if you can otherwise provide a means to reach the file and promote it.